# Explanation needed for this C++ Class

Tags: c++

i got something like this in my C++ header file

```
#define CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(Type, FuncName, BitCount)   \
protected:      \
    Type m_k##FuncName : BitCount; \
public:         \
    Type const FuncName()const{return m_k##FuncName;}   \
    void FuncName(Type const& Value){m_k##FuncName = Value;}

typedef struct tagTest
{
public:
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test1, 10);//10
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test2, 7);//17
    unsigned __int64 Test3:4;
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test4, 8);//29
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test5, 4);//33
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test6, 8);//41
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test7, 4);//45
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test8, 8);//53
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test9, 4);//57
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test10, 1);//58
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test11, 1);//59
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test12, 1);//60
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test13, 1);//61
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test14, 1);//62
    CLASS_DECLARATION_S_BIT(unsigned __int64, Test15, 2);//64

    __int64 Field_1()const{return *(((__int64 const*)(this))+0);}
    void Field_1(__int64 const &kValue){*(((__int64*)(this))+0) = kValue;}
}TestInfo;
```

My question regarding to this is now what does the bottom two lines for Field_1 do?
Can someone please explain that to me, Thanks

Comment: The last two lines looks like someone's variation of the `offsetof()` macro.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think it's just a way to access all fields packed in a single int64_t (through akward reinterpret_casting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my eyes, this looks like a very akward way of doing bitpacking.

What `Field_1()` does is provide a way to access all values of the various fields (which have been carefully crafted to fit in 64 bits, hence the comments) packed into a single int64_t.

The code abuses the fact that the memory layout of the packed fields allows it to just reinterpret the data stored at that location in memory instead of having to manually create the value by combining the various fields.

It's actually functionally equivalent to this (if I'm reading it right):

```
struct tagTest {
  union {
    struct {
      in64_t Test1 : 10;
      in64_t Test2 : 7;
      ...
    };
    int64_t Field_1;
  };
};
```